Unable to sign in to website using Android Studio Device Manager
I'm currently trying to sign into our company website using Android Studio's Device Manager in order to debug an issue. I'm able to hit our QA environment's website sign in screen which is obviously not publicly accessible. However, when I try to sign in, it seems to just get stuck. I was just wondering if there are any gotchas with Android Studio that I hadn't considered that might be preventing me from accessing this private website on my VPN. Originally I thought it was VPN-related, but then I realized if that was the case, I probably wouldn't be able to hit the sign-in screen either. Is this a common issue with Android Studio, and I need to configure something? Again, this isn't an app I'm running locally. I'm simply trying to run Chrome and browse out to our private QA website.

Different organisations have different network security protocols. I once encountered this when Zero Trust (WARP) was being enforced on our company laptops. Some authentication providers are simply whitelabels, what I mean by that is while your login page might load because it is your company URL, but if the authentication process internally redirects to other URLs (as it does during OAuth), those URLs might be the ones being blocked. Like I said, it pretty much depends on what security protocols your company enforces and if you're allowed to disable them temporarily to see if thats the cause.
